# Make a table in beamer, error in first column

Tags: tables, beamer

I want to show a table in `beamer`.
With this code below, why it's get error, first column size can't be 2 cm, and first column no vertical line? How to fix it?

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, 10pt,notheorems]{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme[named=Red]{structure}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{CONTOH T-NORM DAN T-CONORM}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \caption{Tabel dari t-norm dan t-conorm}
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
            \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
            \begin{tabular}{|m{2cm}|c|c|}
                \hline
                \textbf{Nama}\strut&\textbf{t-norm}&\textbf{t-conorm}\\
                \hline
                Standar&$T_m(x,y)=\min(x,y)$&$C_m(x,y)=\max(x,y)$\\
                \hline
                Jumlah terbatas&$T_b(x,y)=\max(0,x+y-1)$&$C_b(x,y)=\min(1,x+y)$\\
                \hline
                Hasil kali/ jumlah aljabar&$T_p(x,y)=xy$&$C_p(x,y)=x+y-xy$\\
                \hline
                Drastik&$T_D(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    y&\text{jika }x=1\\
                    x&\text{jika }y=1\\
                    0&\text{selainnya}
                \end{cases}$
                &
                $C_D(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    y&\text{jika }x=0\\
                    x&\text{jika }y=0\\
                    1&\text{selainnya}
                \end{cases}
                $
                \\
                \hline
                Nilpoten minimum/ maksimum&$T_{nM}(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    \min(x,y)&\text{jika }x+y> 1\\
                    0&\text{selainnya}
                \end{cases}$&
                $
                C_{nM}(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    \max(x,y)&\text{jika }x+y<1\\
                    1&\text{selainnya}
                \end{cases}
                $
                \\
                \hline
                Hasil kali Hamacher/ Jumlah Einstein&$T_{H_0}(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    0&\text{jika }x=y=0\\
                    \dfrac{xy}{x+y-xy}&\text{selainnya}
                \end{cases}$&
                $
                C_{H_2}(x,y)=\dfrac{x+y}{1+xy}
                $
                \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \label{tabelnorma}
        }
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you get any error messages upon trying to compile your code? I guess the compiler complained about the m column type bring undefined. If this is the case, add the array package to the preamble. Also, do not use resizebox on a table as this will lead to inconsistent font sizes throughout your presentation.

Comment: The error message you show definitely is related to the missing `array` package. Add it to your preamble and you should get the expected output. Regarding error messages in general:  Please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error. Thus, if you get an error message, try to fix it first, before even looking at the pdf file.

Comment: Yes, compiler tell me error in m column type because I'm forget typing array package. I use resizebox because the table size is too large and cropped in the slide.

Comment: I get why you use `resizebox`but do you really have to display all these equations on a single slide? With `resizebox` the font size is quite small and this will make your table hard to read.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Now I have fixed the error for my table.

Comment: I will split the table into two slide as your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would redesign your table as follows:

- remove resize box
- add `array` package (bot already mentioned in comments)
- remove `xcolor`, it is already loaded by `beamer`
- use `\scriptsize` font size
- usec `changepage` package that can increase table width
- use `cellspace` for adding vertical spaces in the last two columns' cells
- reduce width of the first column to 15mm

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, 10pt,notheorems]{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme[named=Red]{structure}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

%\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}
\usepackage{array, cellspace}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{changepage}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{CONTOH T-NORM DAN T-CONORM}
    \begin{table}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \scriptsize
    \centering
\begin{adjustwidth}{-2em}{-2em}
        \caption{Tabel dari t-norm dan t-conorm}
        \label{tabelnorma}
            \begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}m{13mm}|Sc|Sc|}
                \hline
                \textbf{Nama}\strut&\textbf{t-norm}&\textbf{t-conorm}\\
                \hline
                Standar&$T_m(x,y)=\min(x,y)$&$C_m(x,y)=\max(x,y)$\\
                \hline
                Jumlah terbatas&$T_b(x,y)=\max(0,x+y-1)$&$C_b(x,y)=\min(1,x+y)$\\
                \hline
                Hasil kali/ jumlah aljabar&$T_p(x,y)=xy$&$C_p(x,y)=x+y-xy$\\
                \hline
                Drastik&$T_D(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    y&\text{jika }x=1\\
                    x&\text{jika }y=1\\
                    0&\text{selainnya}
                \end{cases}$
                &
                $C_D(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    y&\text{jika }x=0\\
                    x&\text{jika }y=0\\
                    1&\text{selainnya}
                \end{cases}
                $
                \\
                \hline
                Nilpoten minimum/ maksimum&$T_{nM}(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    \min(x,y)&\text{jika }x+y> 1\\
                    0&\text{selainnya}
                \end{cases}$&
                $
                C_{nM}(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    \max(x,y)&\text{jika }x+y<1\\
                    1&\text{selainnya}
                \end{cases}
                $
                \\
                \hline
                Hasil kali Hamacher/ Jumlah Einstein&$T_{H_0}(x,y)=
                \begin{cases}
                    0&\text{jika }x=y=0\\
                    \dfrac{xy}{x+y-xy}&\text{selainnya}
                \end{cases}$&
                $
                C_{H_2}(x,y)=\dfrac{x+y}{1+xy}
                $
                \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
\end{adjustwidth}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Since it's a `beamer` document, I would get rid of the `\begin{table}`, `\caption{…}`, `\label`, and `\end{table}` directives.

Comment: @Mico, You are right. They do not matter much in the presentation. +1 for your nice answer!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that's quite similar to [the one provided by @Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/564765/5001), but without any vertical lines and only one, but well-spaced horizontal line. Since tables (and figures) don't "float" in `beamer` documents, I've also omitted the `\begin{table}`, `\caption`, `\label`, and `\end{table}` instructions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, 10pt,notheorems]{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme[named=Red]{structure}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

%% new:
\usepackage{booktabs,ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\hspace{0pt}\RaggedRight}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} % centered, automatic math

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Contoh $t$-norm dan $t$-conorm}
\scriptsize
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} LCC @{}}
    Nama & \text{$t$-norm} & \text{$t$-conorm} \\
    \midrule
    Standar 
    & T_m(x,y)=\min(x,y) 
    & C_m(x,y)=\max(x,y)\\
    \addlinespace
    Jumlah terbatas 
    & T_b(x,y)=\max(0,x+y-1) 
    & C_b(x,y)=\min(1,x+y)\\
    \addlinespace
    Hasil kali\slash jumlah aljabar 
    & T_p(x,y)=xy 
    & C_p(x,y)=x+y-xy \\
    \addlinespace
    Drastik
    & T_D(x,y)=
     \begin{cases}
     y&\text{jika $x=1$}\\
     x&\text{jika $y=1$}\\
     0&\text{selainnya}
     \end{cases}
    & C_D(x,y)=
     \begin{cases}
     y&\text{jika $x=0$}\\
     x&\text{jika $y=0$}\\
     1&\text{selainnya}
     \end{cases} \\
    \addlinespace
    Nilpoten minimum\slash maksimum 
    &T_{nM}(x,y)=
     \begin{cases}
     \min(x,y)&\text{jika $x+y>1$}\\
     0        &\text{selainnya}
     \end{cases}
    & C_{nM}(x,y)=
     \begin{cases}
     \max(x,y)&\text{jika $x+y<1$}\\
     1        &\text{selainnya}
     \end{cases}
    \\
    \addlinespace
    Hasil kali Hamacher\slash Jumlah Einstein
    &T_{H_0}(x,y)=
     \begin{cases}
     0                & \text{jika $x=y=0$}\\
     \frac{xy}{x+y-xy}& \text{selainnya}
     \end{cases}
    & C_{H_2}(x,y)=\dfrac{x+y}{1+xy}
\end{tabularx}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```